# Dúvida sobre exibir array invertido

Tags: java, array

Poderiam me explicar como funciona para retornar um array com os valores invertidos? Eu peguei esse exercício para fazer, mas não consegui. Então, um colega me deu esse exercício para eu dissecar ele, mas não entendi nada :S.

```
package pct;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Exer5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);
        int[] vetor1 = new int[5];
        int tamanho =  vetor1.length;
        int[] vetor2 = new int[tamanho];

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("Digite um número:");
            vetor1[i] =  teclado.nextInt();

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < vetor1.length; i++) {
            tamanho--;
            vetor2[i] = vetor1[tamanho];
        }

        System.out.println("Os valores invertidos, foram:" +vetor2);
    }
}
```

Minhas dúvidas maiores são no segundo `for`, eu praticamente não entendi nada do que aconteceu ali.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicando o código:

```
// Nome do pacote.
package pct;

// Essa classe serve para ler dados a partir de uma entrada.
import java.util.Scanner;

// Todo o código está dentro de uma classe.
public class Exer5 {

    // Dentro do método main, que é o método principal da aplicação (e o único neste caso).
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Cria um Scanner que lê entradas da entrada padrão (System.in).
        // "teclado" não é a melhor definição disso, mas de qualquer forma,
        // trata-se de um objeto que vai fornecer o que o usuário digitar.
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);

        // Cria um array com 5 posições.
        int[] vetor1 = new int[5];

        // Seria mais fácil fazer assim: int tamanho = 5;
        int tamanho =  vetor1.length;

        // Outro array com 5 posições.
        int[] vetor2 = new int[tamanho];

        // Executa 5 vezes, contando (com i): 0, 1, 2, 3 e 4.
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            // Pede para o usuário digitar algo.
            System.out.println("Digite um número:");

            // Lê o que ele digitou e põe no array.
            vetor1[i] =  teclado.nextInt();

        }

        // Neste ponto o array1 vai estar preenchido com os 5 valores digitados.

        // Executa 5 vezes, contando (com i): 0, 1, 2, 3 e 4.
        for (int i = 0; i < vetor1.length; i++) {

            // A variável tamanho começa com 5.
            // Quando i for 0, tamanho será 4.
            // Quando i for 1, tamanho será 3.
            // ...
            // Quando i for 4, tamanho será 0.
            // Observe que tamanho sempre será a "posição reversa" no array.
            tamanho--;

            // Coloca o elemento de um array na posição reversa do outro.
            vetor2[i] = vetor1[tamanho];
        }

        // Deveria mostrar os valores invertidos. Mas vai dar errado!
        System.out.println("Os valores invertidos, foram:" +vetor2);
    }
}
```

A saída no final será algo parecido com isso:

```
Os valores invertidos, foram:[I@1540e19d
```

Vamos melhorar esse programa:

```
package pct;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercicio5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int tamanhoVetor = 5;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] original = new int[tamanhoVetor];
        int[] inverso = new int[tamanhoVetor];

        for (int i = 0; i < tamanhoVetor; i++) {
            System.out.println("Digite um número:");
            original[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < tamanhoVetor; i++) {
            inverso[i] = original[tamanhoVetor - 1 - i];
        }

        System.out.println("Os valores invertidos foram " + Arrays.toString(inverso));
    }
}
```

A diferença aqui é que eu renomeei algumas variáveis e ao invés de ficar contando a variável `tamanho` de trás para frente, eu uso essa fórmula:

```
inverso[i] = original[tamanhoVetor - 1 - i];
```

Ora, a primeira e a última posição desses dois vetores são `0` e `tamanhoVetor -
 1`. Assim sendo, a posição `tamanhoVetor - 1 - i` será a última quando `i` for `0`, a penúltima quando `i` for `1`, a antepenúltima quando `i` for `2`, etc.

Arrays não têm o método `toString()` sobreescrito, e portanto no `System.out.println`, o resultado é um texto ininteligível e sem sentido. Usando o `Arrays.toString(inverso)`, esse problema é sanado.

Por fim, defino o tamanho em apenas um lugar para não ter `tamanho` e `5` espalhados em vários lugares de forma incoerente. Além disso, a variável do tamanho (que chamei de `tamanhoVetor` para não confundir com a já existente) nunca muda para que as coisas não fiquem tão confusas.

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone**](http://ideone.com/s2RsHY) (preste atenção no campo `stdin` lá no ideone e compare com a saída).

Comment: Eu vou ser sincero. Estou com muitas dificuldade em entender o inverso[i] = original[tamanhoVetor - 1 - i];

Comment: @Hardysec Então vamos calcular. Temos que `tamanhoVetor == 5`. Quando `i == 0`, isso daí dá `inverso[0] = original[5 - 1 - 0];`, ou seja, `inverso[0] = original[4];`. Quando `i == 1`, isso daí dá `inverso[1] = original[5 - 1 - 1];`, ou seja, `inverso[1] = original[3];`. Quando `i == 2`, isso daí dá `inverso[2] = original[5 - 1 - 2];`, ou seja, `inverso[2] = original[3];`... E assim por diante.

Comment: @Hardysec Você vê que a posição dada pela fórmula é sempre o espelho de `i`. O motivo de ser o espelho é que o `i` é quantas casas você avançou desde o início (se `i == 0`, você está no início). Logo, `tamanhoVetor - 1 - i` é quantas casas você voltou a partir do final (a posição `tamanhoVetor - 1` é o final). Se o número de casas que você avança desde o início é o mesmo número de casas que você volta do final, você tem posições espelhadas.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Pude compreender melhor.

Answer (score 1):

No segundo laço de repetição possui uma variável com nome `tamanho` no qual recebe o tamanho do `vetor1`. Desta forma:

```
int tamanho =  vetor1.length;
```

Isso significa que agora `tamanho = 5` pois `vetor1` possui 5 posições. Cada vez que passar pelo `for`, esse tamanho está sendo decrementado com `tamanho--;` que é equivalente a `tamanho = tamanho - 1;`

Sendo assim, ao atribuir `vetor1[tamanho]` ao `vetor2[i]`, ele estará invertendo a ordem do vetor inicial, pegando a ultima posição e inserindo na primeira. Veja o que acontece no laço:

```
vetor2[0] = vetor1[4];
vetor2[1] = vetor1[3];
vetor2[2] = vetor1[2];
vetor2[3] = vetor1[1];
vetor2[4] = vetor1[0];
```